# Smack API - How to display loop jxTaskpane for expand and collapse roster list

Tags: java, smack, jxtaskpane

i have problem to display Taskpane for loop. i have a code to get the groups of roster (Groups : Friends - Business - Company, so on) 
my code is :

```
Roster rost = xmppcon.getRoster();
Collection<RosterGroup> groups = rost.getGroups();

 for(RosterGroup group : groups){
            DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
            model.addElement(group.getEntries());
            String GroupNameCount = group.getName() + "("+group.getEntryCount()+")";
            jXTaskPane1.setTitle(GroupNameCount);
            jXList1.setModel(model);

        }
```

but jxTaskpane not loop, but when i print group name it print 2 line (because in database user A have two group is Friends and NIIT)

sample print

```
System.out.println(group.getName());
```

result:

```
Friends




NIIT
```

Comment: No ideas or solutions for this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the same instances of JXTaskPane and JXList at each iteration of the loop. You should really create one instance (`JXTaskPane jXTaskPane1 = new JXTaskPane()`), and same for the JXList in the loop.

When you've setup the JXTaskPane, add it to the containing component.

Comment: i know it, it try before ask question but not work my code `JXTaskPane taskpane = new JXTaskPane();
            getContentPane().add(taskpane);
            taskpane.setBounds(60, 60, 60, 60);` it just display lasted group

Comment: JXTaskPane are supposed to be added into a JXTaskPaneContainer, not in a JFrame's content pane.